# ValueError at /app/ when accessing model data

Tags: python, django, model

I am new with django, I've learnt by following the documentation, but it seems django doesn't want to retrieve any data from the model, on a new project.

The issue is with the line : `latest_weapons = Weapon.objects.order_by('-id')[:5]`.

I tried other field names, other parameters, but still a value error... :(

If someone has any idea, I would greatly appreciate! >//<

app/views.py :

```
from .models import Weapon

# OK !
def detail(request, weapon_id):
    return HttpResponse("Analyzing weapon n°%s" % weapon_id)

# No way !
def index(request):
    latest_weapons = Weapon.objects.order_by('-id')[:5] # Crash (maybe because it returns None?)
    template = loader.get_template('armory/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_weapons': latest_weapons,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

app/models.py :

```
# The Model
class Weapon(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Identifier
    id_item = models.ForeignKey('Item', models.CASCADE, db_column='ID_Item')  # Global ID of this weapon in the items table.
    lvl = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column='LVL')  # Level of the weapon.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=32)  # Label of the weapon (rewrites item name).
    attack = models.IntegerField(db_column='ATK')  # Attack of the weapon.
    crit = models.IntegerField(db_column='CTR')  # Critical Hit of the weapon.
    weapon_type = models.ForeignKey('WeaponType', models.CASCADE, db_column='Type')  # ID of the weapon type.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Weapons'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # Only returning the name for testing.
```

Trace :

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://nanana.test/armory/

Django Version: 3.2
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['armory.apps.ArmoryConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\wamp64\www-src\nanana\armory\templates\armory\index.html, error at line 1
   set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread
   1 :  {% if latest_weapons %} 
   2 :     <ul>
   3 :     {% for weapon in latest_weapons %}
   4 :         <li><a href="/armory/{{ weapon.id }}/">{{ weapon.name }}</a></li>
   5 :     {% endfor %}
   6 :     </ul>
   7 : {% else %}
   8 :     <p>No weapon available.</p>
   9 : {% endif %}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:/wamp64/www-src/nanana\armory\views.py", line 16, in index
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 311, in render
    if match:
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 284, in __bool__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1167, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "c:\wamp64\www-src\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 19, in inner
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "c:\python\python38-64\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 636, in get_event_loop
    self.set_event_loop(self.new_event_loop())
  File "c:\python\python38-64\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 656, in new_event_loop
    return self._loop_factory()
  File "c:\python\python38-64\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 310, in __init__
    super().__init__(proactor)
  File "c:\python\python38-64\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 633, in __init__
    signal.set_wakeup_fd(self_no)

Exception Type: ValueError at /armory/
Exception Value: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread
```

Also, this morning after booting up it worked "miraculously" without touching anything, but on restart, the error showed up again. o.o

The admin panel works, so does the index but has no template yet.

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace. I can't think how a query could cause a `ValueError` so we need to see what's actually in the stack for that error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did, I hope this is what you wanted to see! :)

Comment: Try to upgrade python. Searching for this error suggests it's fixed in 3.8.1 or 3.8.2

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've found how to deal with it while looking online in the end, at this issue : https://github.com/django/asgiref/issues/143 . I still feel stupid... I should have searched further as it does make sense now!